# Returning a wchar_t in C++

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I'm making a function that return a pointer to a wchar_t, but it returns nothing each time I use it.

Function:

```
wchar_t *Character::getCharHealth() {
    wchar_t charHealth[256];
    swprintf_s(charHealth, L"%d", this->getHealth());
    wprintf(L"%s\n", charHealth);
    wchar_t* cHealth = charHealth;
    return cHealth;
}
```

The getHealth() function:

```
int Character::getHealth() {
    return this->health;
}
```

Where it is used:

```
spriteFont->DrawString(spriteBatch.get(), warrior->getCharHealth(), DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2(40, 0));
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You can use `std::wstring` rather than raw `wchar_t` pointers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a array that's already out of scope, that's, `wchar_t charHealth[256]` belongs to `getCharHealth()` once it's done running it's undefined behaviour to access the `charHealth` array again.

What you could try is allocate a dynamic buffer for `charHealth` and return that instead:

```
wchar_t *Character::getCharHealth() {
    wchar_t* charHealth = new wchar_t[256];
    swprintf_s(charHealth, L"%d", this->getHealth());
    wprintf(L"%s\n", charHealth);
    return charHealth;
}
```

You then **must** remember to `delete[]` it when no longer needed:

```
wchar_t* cHealth = warrior->getCharHealth();
spriteFont->DrawString(spriteBatch.get(), cHealth, DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2(40, 0));
delete[] cHealth;
```

That's very error prone you might forget to `delete[]`. Instead you could use [`std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which automatically deletes the pointer on destruction. That's a technique called [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) if you are no familiar with.

But really, you probably should use a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) to convert the number from `int` to [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), since such a object contains proper string storage optimizations and takes care of any allocation that might be necessary.

```
std::wstring Character::getCharHealth() {
    std::wstring charHealth = std::to_wstring(this->getHealth());
    wprintf(L"%s\n", charHealth.c_str());
    return charHealth;
}
```

To access the raw `const wchar_t*` from a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you should use the [`.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method, like so:

```
spriteFont->DrawString(spriteBatch.get(), warrior->getCharHealth().c_str(), DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2(40, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

`cHealth` is a pointer to `charHealth`, which is local to the `getCharHealth` function. Once the function returns, the memory used by `charHealth` is deallocated, so `cHealth` is a wild pointer. One possible solution would be to allocate space for `charHealth` on the heap using `new` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to return `wchar_t charHealth[256];`

However, this is a local variable and is destroyed at the end of the function. While you can take its address it means nothing once you exit the function so that's why you can't use the return.

If you want to return an array you make in a function, you need to explictely allocate it with `new`:
`wchar_t *charHealth = new wchar_t[256];`

Comment: There are also other problems in your code (such as allocating a huge string for storing only an integer and also using `wchar_t` in the first place which tends to be a bad idea) but I only answered the issue you raised

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by return a local allocated array on the stack. After your function `Character::getCharHealth` return, the memory space will be overwrite by your program.

Your `gcc` or `clang` compiler should output warning message for this, double check these msg could save much of your time.

For clang, the warning is controled by flag `-Wreturn-stack-address`, which is defaultly turned  on. For gcc, the warning is controled by flag `-Wreturn-local-addr`, which is also turned on defaultly.